# Labeling in Mathematica to match the font size same as in LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, miktex, labels, wolfram-mathematica

I have some plot

```
Plot[a, {a, -6, 6}]
```

[image]

I need to use it in Latex. However the problem is that labeling text style in Mathematica does not match with LaTeX text. So what I do, I copy the figure without labels from Mathematica as
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pra,preprint]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}

     \begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{2cm}
 \begin{picture} (6,5)


\put(5.12,1.15){$0$}

\put(3.0,2.6){$0.3$}
\put(3.0,3.85){$0.6$}


\put(3,1){\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=6cm]{a2.png} }
 \put(2.9,2.15){$-6$} 
 \put(6.9,2.15){$6$} 
 \put(4.8,3.9){$6$}
  \put(4.8,1.0){$6$}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

and place labels manually in LaTeX as
[image]

As there is a clear difference in label style fonts.
This technique is not only tiring but it will not support me to save the labeled figure in .png or .eps format. Rather it will be a .pdf generated.
Is there a way to match the label font style and size of labeling text in Mathematica?

Comment: There's no general solution to this sort of tool mismatch - your options are (a) either to set up Mathematica to match your Latex style or (b) to redraw your graphs using one of the (many) Latex-friendly systems, like pgfplots.  Assuming that you are doing rather more complex graphs than your example, you might find (a) easier.  If you can use `xelatex` or `lualatex` you would be able to use the same system fonts in both Mathematica and LaTeX, which also might make (a) the better option.

Comment: You can open the pdf-file in Inkscape and export it as PDF+LaTeX, which replaces the text with LaTeX-Text, so you automatically get the same fonts in your document.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution actually.
By selecting the Font Style of Times Roman in MikteX by using package

```
mathptmx
```

And by selecting Label style in Mathematica as

```
LabelStyle -> Directive[ FontFamily -> "Times"]
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MaTeX Mathematica package](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) to generate figure labels with LaTeX in Mathematica.  This is described here:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76943/12

How to match font *sizes* is a slightly different topic and is explained here:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/750/12